# Call ASMX WebMethod From Windows Application using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx, windows

i define a Web method in my web site like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int GetMemberArticleCount(int UserID){
    return 1;
}
```

Now i need call this method from my windows form application. i need to send my user id to method and get the method result. how i can do this?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, what have you tried?

Comment: thanks John, i know that. but i have no time to learn WCF Technology. are you know any quick way to do this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `static` method as a "WebMethod". That only works in an ASP.NET application, and then only when the method will only be called from the web application.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's not worked. how i can get information from my web site database using windows form?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need to get some information about my site users by windows form or silverlight.

Comment: Nobody  here can help you with that, without knowing a lot more about your site. Where is this information stored, for instance? Why did you even _think_ about web services?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing this method as-is may not be possible due to being a security concern.

You can instead make it available through a webservice (WCf, SOAP, REST, etc.).

Please check out the following example to gather a general idea on how you can accomplish this.  This example explains how you can create a web service which will expose the webmethod you have.  Then you can consume that webservice from another application.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/calling-a-web-service-into-another-web-service-application/

Because we do not know your entire solution so far, or what you have already tried, we cannot truly give you the best appropriate answer.

Comment: how i can do it? please giv me a tutorial or article link. thanks.